# Почему работает только один медиа запрос?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Почему может работать только один медиа запрос? На 1024 после уже не работает!

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  ul li a {
    padding-right: 23px;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-right: 260px;
  }
  .block-testimonial {
    min-width: 240px;
  }
  .block-services {
    max-width: 328px;
  }
  .wrap-gallery>div>img {
    width: 328px;
  }
  .block-features {
    max-width: 328px;
  }
  .contact-row1 {
    width: 86%;
  }
  .copyright-item {
    width: 58%;
  }
  .menu-footer {
    width: 42%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался!) В chrome не работал.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Добавил, и все ок)